# Search in Man page for words at the beginning of line

Tags: regex, search, manpage, less-unix

For me, it happens a lot when I want to search for an specific option in man page. I know that options are at the beginning of lines, but don't know how to limit the search.
I've tried `/^REG-PATT`, but it didn't work for me.
What is the shortest correct pattern that I can use ?

Comment: I think the full answer to this question is _depends on your system_. `less` is sometimes used for `man` paging, and `less` can be compiled with different regex engines.

Comment: I don't think so. It's about searching patterns in `less`. how so ?

Comment: from `man less`: _The pattern is a regular expression, as recognized by the regular expression  library  supplied  by your system_. Furthermore your question doesn't specifically mention `less` at all

Comment: Thanks for clarification. In that case, I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some space before the options. Maybe `^\s*-o` (`-o` is the option you are searching) works. Or you can simply search the option in the whole line (`-o`).

Comment: Yeah, that't working, thanks. But it's a little bit awkward, Do you know any other shortcuts instead of typing this every time ?

Comment: I just use `^ *foo` since I haven't ever seen a tab character in a rendered man page. And also... what the... `less` does perl regexps now? Are there any POSIX EREs left in the world? Do people even know that `\s` is non-standard?

Comment: @AlanCurry I think `^ *-foo` is the closest answer. `^\s*` works on the linux machines that I tried, but not, e.g. on OSX.

Comment: @pb2q It depends on the regexp engine used. For example, I tried it with Python's re module and it worked, but it didn't with GNU grep.

Comment: That's my point, the answer to this depends on your system: which pager/regex engine.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` it out with context, e.g. to list what `-x` switch of `tar` does:

```
man tar | grep -C5 -- "-x\b"
```

#### Edit

For getting documentation on `-static` from `gcc(1)`, you could do something like this with GNU sed:

```
man gcc | sed -n '/^ *-static/,/^ *-.*/p'
```

Note that the last line is from the next paragraph.

Here's a more elaborate and precise solution using GNU awk:

```
man gcc | gawk -v RS='\n\n' -v ORS='\n\n' '
 /(^|\n) *-static/ { state = "printing"    ; print "--" }
!/(^|\n) *-static/ { state = "not printing"             }
state == "printing"
'
```

Comment: Try it with something like `-static` for gcc. Not so much helpful. BTW, tricky solution.

Comment: Try the `sed` or `awk` solution.

Answer (score -2):

You might be able to try:

$man command | head

Comment: this will typically only cut off the options